# Update value from database with the hashed content from another column

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, bcrypt, knex.js

I' am trying to create a nodejs migration to add a new column to my table and update all the old records with the hashed content from another column in that same row. I'am using Knex by the way.

I tried to use bcrypt to hash the content but I'am having some difficulties acessing the content from the row. What I have right now is this:

```
return knex.raw(
`UPDATE ${schema}.${tableName} tm
 SET hashed_transfer_information = ${await bcrypt.hash(tm.transfer_method_information), 10}`
);
```

The problem is that this way I can't access the content from the row?

Can you guys help?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in postgres, but I don't know if the blowfish algorithm used there is compatible with your client-side bcrypt implementation.

```
`UPDATE ${schema}.${tableName} 
 SET hashed_transfer_information 
      = crypt(transfer_method_information,gen_salt('bf', 10))`
```

You might need to enable the pgcrypto extension first by executing (SQL):

```
CREATE EXTENSION pgcrypto;
```

Answer (score 1):

To complete clamp's answer with knex syntax:

```
knex('tableName').withSchema('schema')
  .update(
    'hashed_transfer_information', 
    knex.raw(`crypt(transfer_method_information, gen_salt('bf', 10))`)
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [clamp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10667839/clamp) and [Mikael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/360060/mikael-lepist%c3%b6), that was interesting. I'd never bothered to hash a password in the database
before!

Just to check on clamp's question around compatibility, I ran up the following:

```
const secret = "wombats";
const notTheSecret = "notwombats";

knex("users")
  .update("hash", knex.raw(`crypt('${secret}', gen_salt('bf', 10))`))
  .then(() =>
    knex("users").then(async users => {
      for (let user of users) {
        console.log(
          `Password is '${secret}' ...`,
          await bcrypt.compare(secret, user.hash)
        );
        console.log(
          `Password is '${notTheSecret}' ...`,
          await bcrypt.compare(notTheSecret, user.hash)
        );
      }
    })
  );
```

Turns out, it works just fine:

```
Password is 'wombats' ... true
Password is 'notwombats' ... false
Password is 'wombats' ... true
Password is 'notwombats' ... false
```